# Private Nuget Server Returning 503 error for me, but nobody else

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-server

Okay, here's another weird one...

I have installed and setup an in house nuget server for our company - it is running the latest version on nuget (2.2.31210.9045). I can hit the url in my browser (http://{server}) and (http://{server}/nuget) and (http://{server}/nuget/packages) and get all the expected responses.

However, in Visual Studio 2012 I added http://{server}/nuget/ as a custom feed and when I load up the package manager, i get "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable."

I tried this on a few other coworkers' machines and they are able to browse the packages on the server, it seems to only be me.

I cannot find any information on this, or how to debug it. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to reset this or see if there are some troubleshooting steps i can take to figure out what might be going on.

Note: I have had issues before with network connectivity and my install of vs2012 (resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806979/visual-studio-2012-crashes-after-installing-ie9-faulting-module-ntdll-dll))

Comment: Have you tried doing this while Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/) was running?  You might also want to run ELMAH on the server to see if that can reveal any interesting exceptions.

Comment: I did run fiddler and it doesn't pick up the requests, I'm guessing because vs doesn't go through the same local proxy that fiddler sets up...

Elmah, unfortunately was turned off by production control and it is a huge politic battle to get them to help me with this since it works for everyone but myself. Still trying to get them to give me some logs or something from the server.

Comment: Can you setup a package store locally and see if you are able to access packages from that store? Just to iron out the issue with antivirus or firewall related stuff. Also try clearing the cache (%appdata%\Nuget\), and setup the server again.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I can set up a local folder and it works fine. It should not be a firewall issue since it's managed by GP and my peers (on the same GP) are able to access it. Also, I have deleted the nuget local cache and still no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying everything I could think of multiple times without success, I ran across this:

http://wangz.itysc.com/2012/08/nuget-install-package-remote-server.html

Tony says he had a similar problem with VS2010 (and I do have 2010 installed) so, out of desperation I installed that [Service Pack](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=38654) (which doesn't appear to be related) and it magically fixed it in VS2012!

Comment: Just to add, I had this issue and it was because my computer had environment variables for HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY and no one else did

Comment: Yup, the HTTP_PROXY environment variable that I added for my npm setup, screwed this up! Removing that variable resolved my issue.

Comment: This solved my problem as well. By deleting the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY from environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

try the following 2 commands

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:80/  
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:443/
```

then restart visual studio and check. Plese [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153187/what-is-phrase-url-reservation-in-http-sys-means)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the documentation for this and then tried to run it, but for both commands, i'm receiving

URL reservation delete failed, Error: 2
They system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: That means, you are not having any existing reservations